# Why when I type * over double slashes '//' doesn't vim highlight it as a search word?

Tags: search

Let's say I have

```
// that is just a comment
// that is just a comment
// that is just a comment
// that is just a comment
// that is just a comment
```

And I want to type * at `//` to use the command `cgn` and then typing just `.` instead of classical `n .` getting this result:

```
/* that is just a comment
/* that is just a comment
/* that is just a comment
/* that is just a comment
/* that is just a comment
```

My solutin was setting search register manually:

```
:let @/='//'
```

Is there a faster solution?
I know visual block changing but my question is just for better understanding of vim.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that this isn't working for you is that forward slash `/` (ASCII 47), isn't included in your `'iskeyword'` setting, which in Vim defaults to `@,48-57,_,192-255`.<sup>1</sup>

You *could* fix it by adding the forward slash to your `'iskeyword'` setting but I **wouldn't recommend doing this**:

```
:setlocal iskeyword+=/
```

The `'iskeyword'` setting is used in many places in Vim, and there's a fairly decent chance that by adding forward slash to it you will break things. e.g. Do you like being able to step through the components of a path with the `w` motion?

Slightly quicker than setting the search register with a `:let` command is just searching:

```
/\/\/
```

If you find the construction of regular expressions to be slow, you could also take advantage of the method the `*` uses for selecting what to search for:

> 1. the keyword under the cursor |'iskeyword'|
> 2. the first keyword after the cursor, in the current line
> 3. the non-blank word under the cursor
> 4. [...]

In order that steps 1 & 2 don't find anything, construct a line which contains no keywords, search for it, and then remove it again, by typing:

```
o//<Esc>*u
```

You can then carry on with your `cgn` replacements.

For more details on the `'iskeyword'` setting, see `:help 'iskeyword'` and `:help 'isfname'` (the latter just for the description of the format of the former), and for more details of how `*` works see `:help *`.

<sub>1: Except on Windows, where it's slightly different: `@,48-57,_,128-167,224-235`</sub>

Comment: interestingly, if `//` is the only thing on the line, `*` 'works' (presumably the same is true with any symbols)

Comment: @Mass: Yup. See the edit I was writing while you wrote your comment :)

Comment: As I thought we ended up learning a lot more about vim with this question. We have a nice video about `cgn` [here](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `?//<cr>` which is quite fast to type.  Since `n` would now work backwards, you'd have to do `cgN` if you cared about order.  Or you could type `/<cr>` to forward-ize the search.

Comment: Searching backwards is super clever! (Might want to explain *why* it helps, though? I don't think it's obvious.)